# ASP .NET Core 8.0 Web API : service not binding to localhost as expected

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I've been scratching my head for a little while on this problem. I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 5 app (yes, I know it's legacy, but it's a need for a short term solution while we modernize). This is just a web interface that wraps an API, so the logic is largely abstracted. The UI isn't the issue, but I thought context might help here. The real issue is with the API.

I'm not well versed in the details of .NET 8.0 API development, so forgive my ignorance. The following is showing in my console when running my API executable:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:5678
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\
```

Primarily, the `http://[::]:5678` section confuses me. This code was working earlier this week showing `http://localhost:5678` instead. Is this a Kestrel/CORS issue? Is [::] shorthand for localhost? It does look like IPv6 notation, but I've done nothing to my system that would indicate a change to IPv6 preference. I've tried rebooting VS 2022, restarting my machine, rebuilding/clean building, etc. So I'm a bit stumped.

My current API `appsettings.json` is very close to an off-the-shelf `appsettings.json` file; which is to say it looks like the following:

```
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApiUrl": "http://localhost:5678/"
}
```

The API `Program.cs` file looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();

        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

I can provide more detail if need be, but I'm not really sure what information is needed beyond this, so please feel free to clue me in there! I've also looked around for the `[::]` string in web/stack exchange searches to no avail.

** UPDATE **
Per Ibram Reda's request, the launchSettings.json file is here:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:65486",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "FeatureFlagsAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5678",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK it is as you’ve said, `::` is the IPv6 version of `127.0.0.1`. I would assume everything to work normally and be accessible via `http://localhost:5678`. Does it not work or are you just asking out of curiosity?

Comment: How do you launch the app ... could you include  `Properties/launchSettings.json` file in the question for more information

Comment: localhost is `::1`, not just `::`.

Comment: `::` represents an IPv6 address that consists of all zeroes, which is the "unspecified address" [[reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Representation)].  I would suggest creating a new project from the template, confirm that you see "localhost", and then do a diff of the two projects (I recommend using WinMerge on the folders to compare *everything*). Look for something that could be a substantive change.

Comment: BenderBoy - It doesn't currently work outside of Visual Studio, which isn't a good thing for my need.

IbramReda - I've updated the post to include that file's contents. For further context, this works fine in Visual Studio, but if I run it from the .exe, it gives this IP binding that I'm asking about.

madreflection - I've made a fresh app of the same type and it's exhibiting the same behavior. Not sure what changed, but a great suggestion. It must be my machine in some way. Thanks!

Comment: The best I can say is that Windows had some sort of setting switch by an IT Admin. My API is now working for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather unsatisfactorily, this issue seems to have resolved itself. I'm able to use localhost and the IP is showing as expected. I can only imagine that an app or setting was added/changed by IT administration, but I'm not 100% sure. All my other research affirms what BenderBoy said in the comments of the post.